# Is 'No Workload identity for a node level' or 'failure to load CA secret' stopping service mesh from working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, istio, servicemesh, google-anthos-service-mesh

This is the first time I have been trying to install managed Anthos into one of the clusters in GKE. I admit I do not fully understand the full process of installation and troubleshooting I have already done.

It looks like a managed service has failed to install.
When I run:

```
kubectl describe controlplanerevision asm-managed -n istio-system
```

I get this status:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-03-15T14:16:21Z
    Message:               The provisioning process has not completed successfully
    Reason:                NotProvisioned
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Reconciled
    Last Transition Time:  2022-03-15T14:16:21Z
    Message:               Provisioning has finished
    Reason:                ProvisioningFinished
    Status:                True
    Type:                  ProvisioningFinished
    Last Transition Time:  2022-03-15T14:16:21Z
    Message:               Workload identity is not enabled at node level
    Reason:                PreconditionFailed
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Stalled
Events:                    <none>
```

However, I have Workload identity enabled on a cluster level and I cannot see any options in GCP Console to set that for just a node level.

[image]

I am not sure if this is related to `istiod-asm-1125-0` logging some errors. One of them is about failure to load CA secret:

[image]

Nevertheless, the service mesh does not show as added or connected in Anthos Dashboard. The cluster is registered with Anthos.[image]

Comment: If Workload Identity is the culprit here - you can either [create a new node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#option_1_node_pool_creation_with_recommended) which will run your workload or [update the existing one](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#option_2_node_pool_modification) (you may expect some downtime).Also - if this doesn't help you please update your question with the reproductions steps and describe your setup better so we can troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I created a new node pool with more CPU and more nodes as I was getting warning about not having enough CPU. Istio service mesh increases the need for CPU.
2. I migrated my deployment from old node pool to the new one.
3. I run `istioctl analyze -A` and found a few warnings about `istio-injection` not being enabled in a few namespaces. I fixed that.
4. I re run `asmcli install` command without `CA`

`./asmcli install --project_id my-app --cluster_name my-cluster --cluster_location europe-west1-b --fleet_id my-app --output_dir anthos-service-mesh --enable_all`

All or some of the above did the trick.